# Voting Api From iOS

Tags: rating

Hi I created an app for a drupal site and everything is working fine as I used the DIOS Library by workhabit the only thing that's missing is voting. I found this link http://drupal.org/node/241453 which got me close to everything working.

I just keep getting a 401 unauthorized in my response headers but I can't figure out why I'm unauthorized as I'm passing the session data and everything any help would be greatly appreciated!

My setVote method from my module looks like this

```
'actions' => array(
        'setVote' => array(
          'callback' => 'votingapi_service_set_vote',
          'access arguments' => array('edit votes'),
          'args' => array(
          array(
          'name' => 'content_type',
          'type' => 'string',
          'description' => t('Content type'),
          'source' => array('data' => 'content_type'),
          'default value' => 'node',
          ),
          array(
          'name' => 'content_id',
          'type' => 'string',
          'description' => t('Content id'),
          'source' => array('data' => 'content_id'),
          ),
          array(
          'name' => 'vote',
          'type' => 'string',
          'description' => t('Vote'),
          'source' => array('data' => 'value'),
          ),
          array(
          'name' => 'uid',
          'type' => 'string',
          'optional' => TRUE,
          'description' => t('User id'),
          'source' => array('data' => 'uid'),
          ),
        ),
        'return' => 'array',
        'help' => t('Sets vote'),
      ),
```

So I set up my code in my app like this

```
NSMutableDictionary *voteData = [NSMutableDictionary new];
            [voteData setValue:@"highdea" forKey:@"content_type"];
            [voteData setValue:nid forKey:@"content_id"];
            [voteData setValue:@"1" forKey:@"vote"];
            [voteData setValue:[[[[DIOSSession sharedSession] user] objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"uid"] forKey:@"uid"];
            [DIOSVote voteUpDown:voteData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }];
```

And here is the DIOSVote Method which I just created and added to the DIOS library

```
+ (void)voteUpDown:(NSDictionary *)vote
            success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)) success
            failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)) failure {

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", kDiosEndpoint, kDiosBaseVote];

    if ([[DIOSSession sharedSession] signRequests]) {
        [[DIOSSession sharedSession] sendSignedRequestWithPath:path
                                                        method:@"POST"
                                                        params:vote
                                                       success:success
                                                       failure:failure];
    } else {
        [[DIOSSession sharedSession] postPath:path
                                   parameters:vote
                                      success:success
                                      failure:failure];
    }
}
```

All and all here is my result
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just being a permissions issue :) had to just check the boxes so that my app had permission to vote sorry for overlooking such a small thing

Answer (score 2):

Services voting api has a bug, try changing `$votes['votes']` to `$votes['value']` in the resource inc file and passing the vote value there.

Current:

```
function _services_votingapi_resource_set_votes($votes, $criteria) {

  if (empty($votes['entity_id'])) {
    return services_error(t('Missing entity ID.'));
  }

  if (empty($votes['votes'])) {
    return services_error(t('Missing votes amount.'));
  }

  return votingapi_set_votes($votes, $criteria);
}
```

vs:

```
function _scmp_services_resource_set_votes($votes, $criteria) {

  if (empty($votes['entity_id'])) {
    return services_error(t('Missing entity ID.'));
  }

  if (empty($votes['value'])) {
    return services_error(t('Missing votes amount.'));
  }

  return votingapi_set_votes($votes, $criteria);
}
```

You can then test by passing the votes array in the request.

[image: Firefox Poster Voting API Set Votes]

Comment: So it does. That corrected my own immediate problem. Thanks for the clear instructions and screenshot.